# Mapping mixed type objects with Gson

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I'm trying to a data model from a json feed. How can I map a mix- typed object within an object?

The `base_data` object has `pager` being `Map<String,String>` and `result` being `List<Map<String,String>`. Is it possible to create another class `BaseData` to map the object and import back to the Model Class? For example:

```
public class Model{

   private Map <String,BaseData> base_data;
}
```

However I'm getting an mixmatch error in `getBaseData()`

Entire Code:

Json Object:

```
{
  "id": "2",
  "type":"book",
  "base_data": {
    "result": [
      {
        "retailer": "Amazon",
        "price": "$50"
      },
      {
        "retailer": "Target",
        "price": "$60"
      }
    ],
    "pager": {
      "current_page": "5",
      "link": "www.somesite.com"
    }
  }
}
```

Model class

```
import com.BaseData;

public class Model{

    private String id;

    private String type;

    private Map <String,BaseData> base_data;

    public List<Map<String,String>> getBaseData(){

        return base_data.get("result");
                    ^^^^^^ Error Type mismatch: cannot convert from BaseData to List<Map<String,String>>
    }

}
```

BaseData class

```
public class BaseData{

    Map<String,String>pager;

    List<Map<String,String>> result;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace **private Map  base_data;** by **BaseData base_data;**

I tested the following code and worked.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonObject json  = parser.parse("{\"id\":\"2\",\"type\":\"book\",\"base_data\":{\"result\":[{\"retailer\":\"Amazon\",\"price\":\"$50\"},{\"retailer\":\"Target\",\"price\":\"$60\"}],\"pager\":{\"current_page\":\"5\",\"link\":\"www.somesite.com\"}}}").getAsJsonObject();

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Model model = gson.fromJson(json, Model.class);

    }
}

class Model {
    String id;
    String type;
    BaseData base_data;
}

class BaseData {
    Map<String, String> pager;
    List<Map<String,String>> result;
}

class Result {
    String retailer;
    String price;
}
```

If you want to return `List<Map<String,String>>` on the method **getBaseData()** you can convert **BaseData** to `List<Map<String,String>>` in the method

Answer (score 1):

use below link to generate pojo classes.
just paste your json response in given box and give desired name of class. and other details.

click on "Zip" button below the json box. you will get Java class. use it. enjoy..

http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Answer (score 1):

You are returning the wrong type:

```
public List<Map<String,String>> getBaseData(){
    return base_data.get("result");
}
```

The method declaration should be changed to:

```
public BaseData getBaseData(){
    return base_data.get("result");
}
```

Because by calling `base_data.get("result")` you are basicly getting the object from the type BaseData inside the map.

This should solve the mixed type error, not sure it solves what you are atempting to do though